# Copying a specific range from one worksheet to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which I'd like to comb through for a specific program name. When that program name is found, my code would select the correct row from columns `A` to `CV`, and would continue to do that until the last row has cell values. Finally it would copy the selected rows and paste them into a new workbook that is created.

With that being said, my `rng` union (in my `For i` loop) is not working for some reason. It's copying values from the *new* workbook that I am creating rather than from the workbook, **wbthis**. I've tried using `test.Range(Cells(i,1), Cells(i, 78))`, but that doesn't work either. The commented `For` loop that selects the entire row works, but I don't want the entire row.

```
Sub ProgramExport()
  'Dim arr

  'arr3 = Array("Accessible Pedestrian Signals", "Advanced Traffic Signal Control ", "Bathurst Street Bridge Rehabilitation ", "C.I. Centennial Pk Path", _
               "C.I. Etobicoke Valley PK", "C.I. Humber Trail Extension and Gaps", "C.I. Pan Am Trail Expansion - Gatineau Trail", _
               "City Bridge Rehabilitation ", "City-10-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 3", _
               "City-11-King Street Modelling Study", "City-12-REimagining Yonge North Study", "City-15-Flemingdon Park-Thorncliffe Park Neighbourhood  Cycling Connections", _
               "City-22-Accessible Pedestrian Signals Expansion", "City-26-Geometric Safety Improvements - Removal of Channelized Right Turns", _
               "City-27-Missing sidewalk links - 2017", "City-28-Missing sidewalk links - 2018", "City-37-Installation of Cycling Facilites on Woodbine Ave.", _
               "City-38-Installation of Cycling Facilities on Lakeshore Blvd West", "City-39-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 1", _
               "City-40-King Street Pilot Implementation", "City-42-Yonge Tomorrow", "City-6-Eglinton Connects Streetscape Improvements and Cycle Tracks", _
               "City-8-East Don Trail", "City-9-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 2", "Critical Interim Road Rehabilitation ", _
               "Cycling Infrastructure ", "Design of Cherry St Realignment and Bridges", "Ditch Rehabilitation and Culvert Reconstruction", _
               "Don Valley Parkway Rehabilitation", "Engineering Studies", "F.G. Gardiner Interim Repairs", "Facility Improvements ", _
               "Georgetown South City Infrastructure Upgrades", "Greenville and Yonge Street Improvements", _
               "Growth Related Capital Works ", "Guide Rail Replacement Program", "John Street Revitalization Project", "King Liberty Cycling Pedestrian Bridge", _
               "Laneways", "LARP (Lawrence-Allen Revitalization Project) Phase 1", "LED signal Module Conversion ", "Legion Road Extension & Grade Separation", _
               "Local Road Rehabilitation", "Local Speed Limit Reduction", "Major Roads Rehabilitation", "Major SOGR Pooled Contingency ", _
               "N.I. Mill Street Streetscape", "N.I. The Queensway from Islington to Royal York", "Neighborhood Improvements", _
               "North York Service Road Extension", "Pedestrian Safety and Infrastructure Program", _
               "Port Union Road ( Lawrence Ave - Kingston Rd)", "PSI Homewood Depressed Curb", "PXO Visibility Enhancement", _
               "Regent Park Revitalization ", "Retaining Walls Rehabilitation ", "Road Safety Plan (LGTSI) ", "Rouge National Park ", _
               "Salt Management Program", "Sidewalks", "Signs and Markings Asset Management", "Six Points Interchange Redevelopment", _
               "SM Bay Cloverdale", "SM McGill-Granby Village", "SM The Upper Avenue", "Steeles Widenings ( Tapscott Road - Beare Road) ", _
               "System Enhancements for Road Repair & Permits", "Tactile Domes Installation", "Third Party Signals ", "Traffic - Control RESCU", _
               "Traffic Calming", "Traffic Congestion Management ", _
               "Traffic Signals Major Modifications", "Transportation Safety & Local Improvement Program ", "Work for TTC & Others", _
               "Yonge Street Revitalization EA Study (Reimagining Yonge)")

  Dim Program As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wbThis As Workbook
  Dim newBook As Workbook
  Dim value As String
  Dim userID As String
  Dim fn As String
  Dim programN As Variant
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim sName As String
  userID = InputBox("Please enter your user id.")

  'For Each programN In arr3
      programN = "Local Road Rehabilitation"
      Set Program = Range("C1:C2000")
      Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
      'UserForm1.Show
      Set wbThis = Workbooks("TS L2L3v111.xlsm")
      Dim test As Worksheet: Set test = wbThis.Worksheets(4)
      'value = InputBox("Please enter the program you'd like to export.")
      fn = "C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & programN & ".xlsx"
      'aFN = "C:\Users\ashaikh5\Desktop\Copy of TS L2L3v11.xlsm"
      newBook.SaveAs (fn)
      'FileFormat:=52

      For i = 1 To 2000
         If test.Cells(i, 3) = programN Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = test.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 78))

                    MsgBox "Range was set"
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 78)))

                    MsgBox "Range was set"
                    Exit For
                End If
         Else
             'something
         End If

      Next i

      'For Each Cell In Program

          'If Cell = programN Then
              'If rng Is Nothing Then
                'Set rng = Cell.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 78))
              'Else
                'r = ActiveCell.Row
                'Set rng = Union(rng, Cell.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 78)))
              'End If
          'Else
              'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

      'End If

      'Next
      Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = newBook.Worksheets(1)
      erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
      If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Copy
      Else
        MsgBox "rng was not set in the for loop"
      End If
      ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial
      'ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
      'ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ws.Columns("A:L").ColumnWidth = 14
      ws.Columns("C").AutoFit
      ws.Columns("N:CM").ColumnWidth = 14
      'Set wbThis = Workbooks("TS L2L3v111.xlsm")

      'Dim test As Worksheet: Set test = wbThis.Worksheets(4)

      test.Rows(2).Copy
      ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
      ws.Columns("F:K").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("F:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("R:Z").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("R:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("AH:AP").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("AH:AP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("AX:BF").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("AX:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("BJ:BN").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("BJ:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("BP:CA").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Range("A1", "CM1").End(xlUp).AutoFilter 1
      ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 13
      ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
      ws.Columns("CW:FX").Clear
      ws.Cells.Validation.Delete
      newBook.Save
      newBook.Close
      'Set newBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & programN & ".xlsm")
      'Dim test1 As Worksheet: Set test1 = newBook.Worksheets(1)
      'test1.ScrollArea = "$A$1:$CV$2000"
     ' newBook.Save
      'newBook.Close

  'Next programN
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work :/

Comment: **Caution** you code `test.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 78))` is actually `test.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 78))` which is not what you want. You want `test.Range(test.Cells(i, 1), test.Cells(i, 78))` or better yet `test.Range("A1").Resize(2000,78)` to get the whole table.

Comment: In short, don't use the `Range(Cells(),Cells())` to pick multiple values. Use `Range("A2").Cell(i,1).Resize(n,m)` type of operation to pick n×m values at the i-th row under "A2".

Comment: I'll try that as well next Tuesday. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before `For i = 1 To 2000` try adding `wbThis.Activate`. Sometimes if the workbook isn't active first, it won't allow you to operate within it.

**EDIT:**

You're also using `ActiveSheet`, which can be dangerous. Given that you're creating a workbook and adding sheets before this line, I'd question what the actual "active sheet" is. If you instead reference the sheet name there, that's a much better practice and ensures you're working with the intended sheet.

Comment: I'll try it out at work next Tuesday and let you know how it goes. Thank you!